# Application design - read data from text file

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create an app which has a predefined set of data(currently a text file) and it reads from it, now how should i implement the data storage such that when i share the app with someone else, i don't have to pass the text file or any other data file(if possible, i can encrypt the contents and give it using a different extension) externally. I just want to give one exe file to the person and the data should be included inside the exe.
anyway to do it ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the text file as [a resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx).

You do not need to change the build (if you are using Visual Studio that is). Visual Studio will embed the resource/file and generate a readonly property for the file so you can access it directly from within your code:

```
string fileContent = YourResourceFile.TheEmbeddedFile;
```

You could split the fileConent per linebreak but the previous line will load the entire file into memory.

```
string[] lines = fileContent.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If the file is too big to be read into memory at once, you could stream the resource as explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).

Comment: do i need to make changes to build mode as mentioned below ?? and how do i reference the contents, i want to read the file line by line, will that be possible ??

Comment: wow....thank you very much....i will post if i have any issues....thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the build mode of the file to `resource`/`embedded resource`, reading from it works different then, this should be answered somewhere though.